# Can't change keyboard layout using keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, input-language

I've recently started using Ubuntu 18.04 and I am facing a very obnoxious problem - there's no way of changing the keyboard layout with ANY keyboard shortcuts, system-wide, not just in a certain program.

At first I thought that my standard shortcut (<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) was interfering with some other shortcut containing <kbd>super</kbd>, but <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> do not function either. However, I am able to change the layout using the tray icon and the `setxkbmap` command in the terminal. I have tried to set shortcuts manually through the custom shortcuts menu, using the same `setxkbmap` command - no dice. I've also attempted to reconfigure the keyboard through the terminal, still no effect. Changing settings in GNOME tweaks doesn't help.

I would really like to evade any kind of reinstallations and such. If this matters in any way - I am using Unity.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem was that I was using Unity. I changed my desktop environment to GNOME, checked the keyboard shortcut settings and found them off. After changing them back to normal and returning to Unity the issue was fixed.